# What will happen if the biceps stop contracting and instead triceps contract?

Tags: muscles

For example if i bend my arm the biceps contract and triceps relax but if I bend my arm and the triceps contract instead of biceps what effect would it have?

Comment: your arm wouldn't bend...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is too trivial

Comment: When your triceps contract your arm straightens out.

Answer (score 2):

This can be termed co-contraction of antagonist muscles, and it can occur in several pathologic processes. It essentially results in a spastic state.

[Yelnik et al.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20878038) describe the state as:

> Spastic co-contraction is defined as an "unwanted, excessive, level of
>   antagonistic muscle activity during voluntary command on an agonist
>   muscle, which is aggravated by tonic stretch in the co-contracting
>   muscle" (2, 8). Spastic co-contraction in patients with spastic
>   paresis is a descending phenomenon, most probably due to misdirection
>   of the supraspinal drive. It may be facilitated by increased recurrent
>   inhibition, causing loss of reciprocal inhibition during voluntary
>   command (2, 9).

For example, this can occur with perinatal brain damage. See a study by [O'Sullivan et al.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9874488) titled "Abnormal development of biceps brachii phasic stretch reflex and persistence of short latency heteronymous reflexes from biceps to triceps brachii in spastic cerebral palsy."

The state of co-contraction can be produced in healthy individuals as well, and studies on joint biomechanics under these conditions have been done. See [Wise et al](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2230868/).